# Rails 3 Unescaping Helper Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, html-helper

I have a helper method that calls two other helper methods, the problem is that when I call it, the view outputs the escaped HTML. I want the actual HTML to be interpreted.

myhelper.rb

```
  def combined(klass)
    content_tag :span, "#{first(klass)} first : #{second(klass)} second"
  end

  def first(klass)
      content_tag :span, 
                  link_to("first", first_path(klass))
  end


  def second(klass)
       content_tag  :span, 
                  link_to("second", second_path(klass))
  end
```

In my view I call `<%= combined(myclass) %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
  def combined(klass)
    content_tag :span, "#{first(klass)} first : #{second(klass)} second".html_safe
  end
```

Was hoping for a more convenient way.